# monacaでcom.google.android.gms.permission.AD_IDを削除したい。

Tags: android, monaca

ビルドしたファイルをGoogle Play Consoleにアップしたところ
「このリリースには com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID 権限が含まれています」
とエラーとなってしまいました。

どうやら、monacaでは自動的にcom.google.android.gms.permission.AD_IDがAndroidManifest.xmlに書き込まれるようです。

そこで、
https://ja.docs.monaca.io/reference/third_party_phonegap/custom_config
の説明に従って、config.xmlに

```
<platform name="android">
・・・
<custom-preference name="android-manifest/uses-permission/[@android:name='com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID']" delete="true" />
・・・
</platform>
```

を書き加えたところ、ビルドは無事完了しましたが、Google Play Consoleにアップし、App Bundleの権限を確認しましたが消えていません。

そこで、

```
<platform name="android">
・・・
<custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" delete="true" />
</custom-config-file>
・・・
</platform>
```

としてみたところ、ビルドに失敗してしまいます。

どうしたらcom.google.android.gms.permission.AD_IDを消せますでしょうか？

Comment: <preference name="android-manifest/uses-permission/[@android:name='com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID']" delete="true" />

で試しましたが駄目でした。

Comment: 以下のプラグインを試してみましたが、ビルドで失敗し採用になりませんでした。

https://github.com/Bphreaker/cordova-plugin-remove-ad-permission